# adjective for "related to monogamy"

Tags: single-word-requests, greek

The "monogamous lifestyle" is a strange word, because lifestyles are not known to be married. I wonder whether a word like "*monogamial" or similar acts in a more appropiate way.

Comment: "(The) monogamous lifestyle" is **not strange,** and it is **not a word**. https://www.google.com/search?q="monogamous lifestyle"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you looking for "monogamist"? The monogamist lifestyle [...]

> a. The practice or condition of being married to only one person at a time.
>
> b. The practice of marrying only once in a lifetime.

Comment: Thank you. This can be used as an adjective, too, can't it? However, I now have come to the conclusion that "monogomial" is still a correct graecicism, albeit not a usual one.

Comment: Correct.  Example: "Monogamist lifestyles are common."

Answer (score 2):

The "monogamous lifestyle" is quite acceptable.

Although it's not easy finding an online definition of "monogamous" rather than the noun, at http://www.audioenglish.org/dictionary/monogamous.htm one can find:

> MONOGAMOUS (adjective)
>    1. (used of relationships and of individuals) having one mate

Hence, monogamous may mean **having one mate**  (a monogamous bird)

or

**of / pertaining to a state where the individual/s has one mate** (a monogamous relationship / society).

Comment: That makes the question general reference/ NARQ.